# How to use standalone with multiple files?

Tags: pdf, page-breaking, standalone

I compile

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\begin{document}
 Test1
\end{document}
```

I do get what I expect.
[image: Test1]

But if I do

```
\documentclass[multi]{standalone}
\begin{document}
 Test1
 \newpage
 Test2
\end{document}
```

I get two large pages with tiny `Test1` and `Test2`.

[image: Test2]

## Question

So, how can I get two cropped PDF `Test1` and `Test2` in the same compiled file?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to enclose each “page” in an environment:

```
\documentclass[multi,crop,border=2]{standalone}

\standaloneenv{my}

\begin{document}

\begin{my}
 Test1
\end{my}

\begin{my}
 Test2
\end{my}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The `multi` option also accepts the environment name, which saves the `\standaloneenv` call: `multi=my`. Note that the environment will be altered at `\begin{document}` so it is ok if it is getting defined in the preamble after the class option or `\standaloneenv`.